# Actionlinks breaks when MapPageRoute added

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, custom-routes

We need to add a .html file which should be part of the root directory of our mvc app so i added the following

```
Route AnnouncementRoute = routes.MapPageRoute
                                      ("Announcement", "Announcement", "~/Announcement.html");

Route DefaultRoute = routes.MapRoute(
                        "Default", // Route name
                        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
                    );
```

The above code makes all the default actionlinks to add Announcement

```
http://localhost/Announcement?action=actionname&controller=controllername
```

How to make sure my actionlinks generated does not contain Announcement in the link as follows which is correct?

```
http://localhost/?action=actionname&controller=controllername
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RouteCollection.IgnoreRoute()`. Here's a good [usage example](http://richhewlett.com/2013/11/10/host-static-html-or-webforms-page-within-mvc-site/) that does exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: We don't want the file to be accessed as site.com/Announcement.html instead we want as site.com/Announcement

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just create an Announcement controller with a single action and view with the contents of Announcement.html?